# C# String creation (specified length)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, string

Is there a succinct way (i.e. not a for loop) to create a string of a specified length?  Doesn't matter what is in the string.

Comment: It always matters what's in a string, because you can't change it later.

Comment: I am unit testing string length validation - the contents don't apply in this case.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [the `string` constructor that takes a `char` and an `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx).  It creates a `string` instance with the `char` repeated the specified number of times.

Answer (score 12):

As bdukes mentions there's constructor, that takes a char and an int. That will construct a string of the given length filled with the char.

However, keep in mind, that strings are immutable in .NET, so if you want to create a specific string buffer, you should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score -3):

why would you want to create a string if you dont want to control what the value of the string would be?

I would suggest using a StringBuilder and using the constructor that takes an int