# Most efficient way to fill a String with a specified length with a specified character?

Tags: java, performance, gwt

Basically given an int, I need to generate a String with the same length containing only the specified character. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313035/c-string-creation-specified-length), but it relates to C# and it *does* matter what's in the String.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214377/limiting-number-of-decimal-places-in-gwt/7216919#7216919), and my answer to it are why I am asking this one. I'm not sure what's the best way to go about it performance wise.

### **Example**

*Method signature:*

```
String getPattern(int length, char character);
```

*Usage:*

```
//returns "zzzzzz"
getPattern(6, 'z');
```

### What I've tried

```
String getPattern(int length, char character) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += character;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is this the best that I can do performance-wise?

Comment: You should have used a char datatype for result and returned using new String, that gives much better performance, see the benchmarks in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of concatenating chars this way. Use [StringBuilder.append()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%29).

StringBuilder will give you better performance. The problem with concatenation the way you are doing is each time a new String (string is immutable) is created then the old string is copied, the new string is appended, and the old String is thrown away. It's a lot of extra work that over a period of type (like in a big for loop) will cause performance degradation.

Comment: Yikes! all your answers came in so quickly (+1 to you all). This answer was first so I'll accept it (Thanks to the others as well!). This _does_ work in GWT (just tried it out) - I should have specified that as a requirement.

Comment: @Trevor Senior - We are super fast at StackOverflow even at 1 AM in the morning. You are welcome!

Comment: Damn my slow typing! I blame the beer.

Comment: @Brian Roach - LOL. I will give +1 for having beer on a Monday morning :P

Comment: @CoolBeans - It's still Sunday night until I <strike>pass out</strike> go to sleep.

Comment: True story: I once inherited a legacy process that I was told "uses a lot of CPU". It was burning up an entire core because of extensive logging doing exactly this.

Answer (score 5):

[`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) from commons-lang or [`Strings`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) from guava are your friends. As already stated **avoid** String concatenations.

```
StringUtils.repeat("a", 3) // => "aaa"
Strings.repeat("hey", 3) // => "heyheyhey"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use primitive char arrays & some standard util classes like [Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

```
public class Test {
    static String getPattern(int length, char character) {
        char[] cArray = new char[length];
        Arrays.fill(cArray, character);
//      return Arrays.toString(cArray);
        return new String(cArray);
    }

static String buildPattern(int length, char character) {
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(character);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    getPattern(10000000,'c');
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    System.out.println(time);           //prints 93
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    buildPattern(10000000,'c');
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    System.out.println(time);          //prints 188
}
```

}

**EDIT** Arrays.toString() gave lower performance since it eventually used a StringBuilder, but the new String did the magic.

Comment: This test is testing the creation of long strings. Could you test lots of short strings and see what the performance is? I'm interested if the array way is still faster.

Comment: @Zammbi : lots of short strings? The snip here only serves for a char variable repeated n times. If you have Strings to concatenate then you should use a StringBuilder. Character sequences are simply not meant for the purpose.

Comment: What I mean you have c repeated 10000000 times. What if the test was c was repeated only about 4-10 times but the test was run 10000000 times. Though I guess it really doesn't matter, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Yikes, no.

A `String` is immutable in java; you can't change it. When you say:

```
result += character;
```

You're creating a new `String` every time.

You want to use a `StringBuilder` and append to it, then return a `String` with its `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be more efficient to do it like following,

```
String getPattern(int length, char character) 
        {
            char[] list = new char[length];
            for(int i =0;i<length;i++)
            {
                list[i] = character;
            }
            return new string(list);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating a String is never the most efficient, since String is immutable, for better performance you should use [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and [append](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28boolean%29)()

```
String getPattern(int length, char character) {
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(length)
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(character);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `new StringBuilder(length)` might help a little performance-wise

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise, I think you'd have better results creating a small `String` and concatenating (using `StringBuilder` of course) until you reach the request size: concatenating/appending "zzz" to "zzz" performs probably betters than concatenating 'z' three times (well, maybe not for such small numbers, but when you reach 100 or so chars, doing ten concatenations of 'z' followed by ten concatenations of "zzzzzzzzzz" is probably better than 100 concatenatinos of 'z').

Also, because you ask about GWT, results will vary a lot between DevMode (pure Java) and "production mode" (running in JS in the browser), and is likely to vary depending on the browser.

The only way to really know is to benchmark, everything else is pure speculation.
And possibly use deferred binding to use the most performing variant in each browser (that's exactly how `StringBuilder` is emulated in GWT).